# How to simplify my resample DataFrame according to specific rules?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with frequency as minutes, time is [['09:30:00'-'11:30:00'],['13:00:00'-'15:00:00']], demo is `generate_date()`,
I want to resample it according to the elapsed hours, but each period of time is closed before and after.

My approach is the `resample() function`:

1. Add a little time to the left.
2. Resample to 30T.
3. Add a small time to 10:00:00 and 11:00:00.
4. Separate morning and afternoon data.
5. The data in the morning is resampled to 30T again, and the data in the afternoon is resampled to H.
6. Combine morning and afternoon data.

Can my `resample()` function be simplified?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


def generate_data():
    datetime1 = pd.date_range('2021-12-01 09:30:00', '2021-12-01 15:00:00', freq='t')
    df = pd.DataFrame(datetime1, columns=['datetime'])
    df['time'] = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    df = df[(df.time <= '11:30:00') | (df.time >= '13:00:00')].reset_index(drop=True)
    np.random.seed(2021)
    df['close'] = np.random.random(len(df)) * 100
    return df


def resample(df):
    df.loc[df['time'].isin(['09:30:00', '13:00:00']), 'datetime'] = df.loc[
        df['time'].isin(['09:30:00', '13:00:00']), 'datetime'].apply(lambda x: x + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.001))
    df = df.set_index('datetime')
    df = df.resample('30T', closed='right', label='right').last()
    df = df.dropna(subset=['close'])
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.loc[:, 'time'] = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    df.loc[df['time'].isin(['10:00:00', '11:00:00']), 'datetime'] = df.loc[
        df['time'].isin(['10:00:00', '11:00:00']), 'datetime'].apply(lambda x: x + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.001))
    df = df.set_index('datetime')
    df1 = df[df.time < '12:00:00']
    df2 = df[df.time > '12:00:00']
    df1 = df1.resample('30T', closed='right', label='right').last()
    df2 = df2.resample('H', closed='right', label='right').last()
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    df = df.dropna(subset=['close'])
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df


def main():

    df = generate_data()
    print('\nBefore resample:')
    print(df)
    df = resample(df)

    print('\nAfter resample:')
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Before resample:
               datetime      time      close
0   2021-12-01 09:30:00  09:30:00  60.597828
1   2021-12-01 09:31:00  09:31:00  73.336936
2   2021-12-01 09:32:00  09:32:00  13.894716
3   2021-12-01 09:33:00  09:33:00  31.267308
4   2021-12-01 09:34:00  09:34:00  99.724328
..                  ...       ...        ...
237 2021-12-01 14:56:00  14:56:00  98.774245
238 2021-12-01 14:57:00  14:57:00  67.903063
239 2021-12-01 14:58:00  14:58:00  40.640360
240 2021-12-01 14:59:00  14:59:00  50.995722
241 2021-12-01 15:00:00  15:00:00  88.935107

[242 rows x 3 columns]

After resample:
             datetime      time      close
0 2021-12-01 10:30:00  10:30:00   6.383650
1 2021-12-01 11:30:00  11:30:00  26.667989
2 2021-12-01 14:00:00  14:00:00  19.255257
3 2021-12-01 15:00:00  15:00:00  88.935107
```

Comment: You want to closed right but you add an offset of 0.001s so closed left and don't add offset, no?

Comment: because it has 242sec,and I need to resample to 4hour, so only one of right or left need offset. I choose to offset left , also can only offset right-0.001s. If offset right ,resample params will be closed='left', label='left'.